# Magento 2 Region list not filter for default country on billing address for first time

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.5, billing-address, country-regions

There are many country region available in region list. The issue arises first-time page load on the billing address of checkout. Even default country has been set up the USA, All region list has been displayed in the select box. After that region filter working perfectly. 
I need to apply the filter so region are displayed based on Default selected country. [image]